# Assembly Language: difference between ja and jg?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

I am having trouble understanding the difference between ja and jg for assembly language. I have a section of code:

```
cmp  dh, dl
j--  hit
```

and am asked which conditional jump to hit (that replaces j-- hit) will be taken with the hex value of DX = 0680.

This would make dl = 06 and dh = 80, so when comparing, 80 > 06. I know that jg fits this as we can directly compare results, but how should I approach solving if ja fits (or in this case, does not fit) this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. If `dx` is 0x0680, then `dh` is 0x06 and `dl` is 0x80.
2. 0x80 is interpreted as 128 in unsigned mode, and -128 in signed mode.
3. Thus, you have to use `jg`, since 6 > -128, but 6 < 128. `jg` does signed comparison; `ja` does unsigned comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo on my OP. Could you revise your answer based on dx = 0680?

Comment: @raphnguyen: Done. Note my first point; you swapped the meaning of `dl` and `dh`.

Comment: Thanks, that was crystal clear. How do I know if dx is 0x0680 or 1x0680?

Comment: @raphnguyen: Um. 0x is a prefix (used in C code, and anything derived from C, such as C++, Java, JS, etc.) for denoting a hexadecimal number. There is no such thing as 1x. :-)

Comment: #Chris Ah I'm sorry for the confusion. So dh = 0x80 and dl = 0x06. The answer to this question was jg, which you said does signed comparison. Since 0x80 in signed mode is -128, how does the cmp work? I thought the cmp and jg statement would be compare if dh > dl. Am I comparing backwards?

Comment: @raphnguyen: I wrote my post based on your original statement that `dx` is 0x0680. But you later said that `dh` is 0x80 and `dl` is 0x06. These are conflicting statements. If the latter is true, then `dx` is 0x8006. You should decide whether `dx` is 0x0680 or 0x8006; those are very different numbers. :-)

Comment: Sorry it's late over here. Mind is not functioning as it should. Let's start from scratch. dx = 0680, dh = 06, dl = 80. If we are cmp dh, dl, we are comparing 06, 80. 6 is not > 128, but 6 > -128. jg does signed comparison, whew. Finally clicking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @raphnguyen: I'm glad that made sense to you in the end. :-) Always glad to help.

Answer (score 9):

The difference between `ja` and `jg` is the fact that comparison is unsigned for `ja` and signed for `jg` (treating the registers as signed vs unsigned integers).

If the numbers are guaranteed to be positive (i.e. the sign bit is 0) then you should be fine.  Otherwise you have to be careful.

You really can't intuit based on the comparison instruction itself if `ja` is applicable.  You have to look at the context and decide if sign will be an issue.